# lifecycle between Parent Fragment and Child Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

All the Fragment inherits from BaseFragment.

And I'd like to give back press event respectively to each fragment. But BaseFragment has default back press event like this.

```
    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        logd("onResume() BaseFragment")
        requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this, backPressCallback)
    }
```

And also the child fragments have

```
    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        logd("onResume() ChildFragment")
        requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this, backPressCallback)
    }
```

It will print,

```
onResume() BaseFragment
onResume() ChildFragment
```

So, the ChildFragment override and when I press back button, ChildFragment's `backPressCallback` is called.

However, when I go out and come back, the order is different.

```
onResume() ChildFragment
onResume() BaseFragment
```

So, the user sees ChildFragment but BaseFragment's `backPressCallback` is called. And it behaves different from what I expected. (ex. I want popBackStack but close the app)

How can I solve this problem? Or is there any method that called after the parent fragment is called?

According to [this article](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/lifecycle), BaseFragment must be called before ChildFragment. But it doesn't seem so.

Answer (score 0):

```
    activity?.onBackPressedDispatcher?.addCallback(
                    viewLifecycleOwner,
                    object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
                        override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
                            try {
                                if (!isChildFragmentOpen)
                                {
                                    val trans: FragmentTransaction =
                                        parentFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                                    trans.remove(Fragment())
                                    trans.commit()
                                }else{
                                    parentFragmentManager.popBackStack()
                                } 
                            } catch (e: Exception) {
                                e.message
                            }
                        }
                    })
```

add this to your fragment.